# Getting a reference to the class instance of a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript class that extends `React.Component`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}>
{
    constructor(props: {})
    {
        super(props);
    }

    public render()
    {
        return <span>Test</span>;
    }

    public MyMethod() {
        console.log("Working fine");
    }
}
```

Then there is a place where I manually have to create an instance and attach this to the DOM:

```
var component = MyComponent;
var element = React.createElement(component, {}, null);
ReactDOM.render(element, myDomElementContainer);
```

Due to architectural constraints of the system, I need to store a reference to my class instance for that component for later use, problem is that I can not find any reference to the instance of my class in the created element, it only have a reference to the class via the property `type`.

`React.createElement` is only allowing me to supply the class, and `ReactDOM.render` does not like a manually instantiated object.

What should I in order to instantiate a custom component, attach it to the DOM and get a reference to the instance of my component class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a few options:

(1) Use the return value from [ReactDOM.render](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render):

```
var element = ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, myDomElementContainer);
```

(2) Use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
var element = React.createElement(MyComponent);
ReactDOM.render(element);
```

(3) Use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute):

```
var element;
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent ref={el => element = el } />, myDomElementContainer);
```

The instance will be assigned to `element` when the instance of `MyComponent` has been rendered.

Comment: Ah, the return value of ReactDOM.render was the key. Although, this seems to differ from React.createElement, that did not return the expected instance.

Comment: What does `React.createElement` return? Should be the react element

Comment: I don't know what type that is supposed to be, but it's not at all the same as the object that I get from ReactDOM.render. It just contains stuff like `target`, `_store`, `_owner`, `_self` `props`, etc. It's not a instance of my component class.

Answer (score 5):

For my scenario I used a singleton (static variable)

```
export let instance = null;

class SearchDialogue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        instance = this;
    }
}
```

then when you need to reference it you can run

```
import {instance as searchDialogueInstance} from './SearchDialogue'

console.log(searchDialogueInstance.someFooBar);
```

## Note

Keep in mind that this only works WELL if you're leveraging the singleton design pattern. If you are not then you could turn the static var into an array and on push new instances into the array. Careful as this could get you into trouble if you are not already familiar with potential memory pitfalls.

```
SearchDialogue.instances.push(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use React.js in a way you using jQuery, and it is not ok. Really, I cannot imagine case that requires doing such things; and I suspect that you should not do this. Please, (1) use jsx to create components, (2) use refs to found component at that jsx. Like

```
...

x(){
    this.refs.c.style={color:'blue'}
}

render() {
    return <div ref='c' style={{border:'1px solid red', height:10}} onClick={this.x.bind(this)}/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I agree that this might not be the react way of doing things, but I'm under a lot of architectural constraints where react is just one possible framework for managing views, and I do need to be able to manage references to the objects responsible for the view, regardless whether they are react, knockout or any other library for managing views.

Comment: Having such links will not help you, as React creates new nodes after props/state changes - I mean, React changes/replaces DOM elements to allow  updating DOM tree after props/state changes - and links you have will be useless sooner or later.

Comment: Yes, but the instance of the component class is the same nevertheless.