# where is instance of class created

Tags: reactjs, class, instance, react-dom

We are shown the following code:

```
class HelloComponent extends React.Component{
   render() {
     return(
            <h1>Hello</h1>
     );
   }
}

ReactDom.render(
    <HelloComponent />, document.getElementById('container)
);
```

Since HelloComponent is a class does ReactDOM.render create an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ReactDOM.render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) method returns a reference to the component.

This mean you can do something like:

```react
const helloComponent = ReactDom.render(
    <HelloComponent />, document.getElementById('container)
);
```

And have a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the component you can use for other purposes if you want.

**NOTE:** This does not work for stateless/functional components.

Comment: do you mean:  const helloComponent = ReactDom.render(
    <h1>hello<h1>, document.getElementById('container)
);

Comment: No, I wrote it as intended. Is it not returning a reference to the DOM element for you? Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147673/getting-a-reference-to-the-class-instance-of-a-component