# Accessing Nearby State ; React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

If I were to have

```
function a(){
     ...
}

export default class App extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
          this.state={
               var b: "value"
          }
     }
}
```

Would there be a way to directly access the state within App out of the nearby non-class function? I'm thinking of something similar to App.setState({}) or anything like that

With function a and class App being written in the same file, but with a just scoped outside of the class.

Comment: what is function a? Is it a child component?

Comment: @Jai ; function a is written in the same file, just scoped outside of the class

Comment: You can call it passing the state: `a (this.state)` `a function(state){ ... }`

Comment: Here was the solution that I found to my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57398896/5819079

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage parent state in child component you can pass handler function as a props and then call it in the child component.

If you want to get an access to fields you can make static fields in App class and then call it by using App.example() - example below.

```
function func() {
    App.example();
}

export default class App extends React.Component{
    static example = () => {
        console.log('Hi - from App');
    }
}
```